# Aggregate Invalid operator '$switch'

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Using mongoose with Mongodb and node.js, I would like to perform an aggregate that needs to determine if a value is time-based so I can convert to seconds if so, and leave as is if not time-based.

I added a $switch operator to the divide operator to perform this operation.   For some reason, I keep getting an error indicating "MongoError: invalid operator '$switch'".

The code is listed below:

```
$divide: [{
    $switch: {
        branches: [
            {
                case: { $eq: [ "$timeType", "min"]},
                then: { $multiply: [ "$route.completedTotal", "60" ] }
            },
            {
                case: { $eq: [ "$timeType", "sec"]},
                then: "$route.completedTotal"
            },
            {
                case: { $eq: [ "$timeType", "hr"]},
                then: { $multiply: [ "$route.completedTotal", "3600" ] }
            }
        ],
        default: "$route.completedTotal"
    }
}, {
    $switch: {
        branches: [
            {
                case: { $eq: [ "$timeType", "min"]},
                then: { $multiply: [ "$route.total", "60" ] }
            },
            {
                case: { $eq: [ "$timeType", "sec"]},
                then: "$route.total"
            },
            {
                case: { $eq: [ "$timeType", "hr"]},
                then: { $multiply: [ "$route.total", "3600" ] }
            }
        ],
        default: "$route.total"
    }
}]
```

How can I fix my $switch operator to make this work?  If I cannot use the $switch operator in this context, what is an alternative approach to fix this logic?

Comment: your mongodb version?

Comment: version: 3.2.11

Comment: You need to update your mongodb version to **3.4** or **3.6** because `$switch` has not been introduced in version prior to **3.4**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted, [`$switch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/switch/) was introduced with MongoDB 3.4. Whilst it's probably a good idea to upgrade to that version where you can, the same statement has been possible ever since the aggregation framework was released using [`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/):

```
"$divide": [
  {
    "$cond": {
      "if": { "$eq": [ "$timeType", "min" ] },
      "then" { "$multiply": [ "$route.completedTotal", "60" ] },
      "else": {
        "$cond": {
          "if": { "$eq": [ "$timeType", "sec"] },
          "then": "$route.completedTotal",
          "else": {
            "$cond": {
              "if": { "$eq": [ "$timeType", "hr"] },
              "then": { "$multiply": [ "$route.completedTotal", "3600" ] },
              "else": "$route.completedTotal"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$cond": {
      "if": { "$eq": [ "$timeType", "min" ] },
      "then": { "$multiply": [ "$route.total", "60" ] },
      "else": {
        "$cond": {
          "if": { "$eq": [ "$timeType", "sec" ] },
          "then": "$route.total",
          "else": {
            "$cond": {
              "if": { "$eq": [ "$timeType", "hr" ] },
              "then": { "$multiply": [ "$route.total", "3600" ] },
              "else": "$route.total"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

That's using the `if/then/else` "keys" syntax for clarify but the earlier array syntax is still valid and basically means the statement can be written all the way back to MongoDB 2.2.

This should make sense because a "switch" statment in any other programming language implementations is merely a "cleaner" way of writing `if/then/else if` in continuation anyway, so it makes sense that anything which does the same thing also produces the same result but just with different syntax.